# How to prevent sign in dialog from popping up when user signs out

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, material-ui, modal-dialog

I have a popup dialog that shows when the user clicks on sign in. This allows the user either to sign in with email/password or google. They can also sign up from here as well.

The issue is that once they sign in, the sign in link changes to sign out. When you click on the sign out link, it signs the user out but then the sign in dialog shows again. From what I can tell it should not be doing this. It checks if there is a currentUser and if so, start the sign out process else show the dialog.

How do I prevent it from showing the dialog when the user signs out?

```
const Header = ({ currentUser, hidden, signOutStart }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <sc.HeaderContainer>
            <sc.LogoContainer to={'/'}>
                <Logo className={'logo'} />
            </sc.LogoContainer>
            <sc.OptionsContainer>
                <sc.OptionLink to={'/shop'}>SHOP</sc.OptionLink>
                <sc.OptionLink to={'/contact'}>CONTACT</sc.OptionLink>
                {currentUser ? (
                    <sc.OptionLink as={'div'} to={'/#'} onClick={signOutStart}>
                        SIGN OUT
                    </sc.OptionLink>
                ) : (
                    <sc.OptionsContainer>
                        <sc.OptionLink onClick={handleClickOpen} to={'/#'}>SIGN IN</sc.OptionLink>
                        <SignInSignUpDialogue onClose={handleClose} open={open} />
                    </sc.OptionsContainer>
                )}
                <CartIcon />
            </sc.OptionsContainer>
            {hidden ? null : <CartDropdownContainer />}
        </sc.HeaderContainer>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
    hidden: selectCartHidden,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    signOutStart: () => dispatch(signOutStart()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added signOut function:

```
const signOut = () => {
    signOutStart();
    setOpen(false);
};
```

and changed:

```
<sc.OptionLink as={'div'} to={'/#'} onClick={signOutStart}>
```

to:

```
<sc.OptionLink as={'div'} to={'/#'} onClick={signOut}>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have onyl 2 options. To show the `Sign in` dialog or the `Sign out` Link and the behaviour you explain makes sense. After yousignout you will see the sign in dialog. That is how the code is written to do so. If you want to awoid that you could create a `route` where the user is informed that he is loged out and a nice logout page is shown without the dialog.

Comment: The reason why this was happening is because after a successful sign in, the dialog closes by itself but the close variable was never being set to false. I added a new function called signOut and called this instead of signOutStart when the link is clicked. Inside the signOut function, I call signOutStart and set open to false. Now the dialog doesn't show when I click sign out.